# MySQL List Set theory, relational database

Tags: mysql, sql, database, relational

```
SELECT business.name FROM business WHERE (3) NOT IN (1,2,3)
```

The above is a valid MySQL statement. But I need a statement which allows the NOT IN condition to work with 2 lists i.e. none of the elements in the first list appear in the second.

E.g.

```
SELECT business.name FROM business WHERE (4, 5) NOT IN (1,2,3)
```

Note: Each list has only integer values, and each list is generated from different tables using nested queries.

Thank You in advance

Comment: Can you provide the actual query, with its subqueries? I think you can `JOIN` the two queries in such a way that you'll get your desired result.

Comment: SELECT file_name,extension, advertID, client_file_name FROM advert WHERE (SELECT categoryID FROM business_categories WHERE businessID = $bizID) NOT IN (SELECT categoryID FROM advert_categories WHERE advert_categories.advertID = advert.advertID)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If values of both lists are retrieved by nested queries,
then you may join resultsets of these two nested queries and check if they have common values.
If yes - that means that some value from list 1 exists in list 2
The final query might look like this:

```
select *
from business
where not exists(
  SELECT 1 FROM 
  ( 
      -- nested query that retrieves values of list 1
      SELECT val FROM list1
  ) x
  JOIN
  (
    -- nested query that retrieves values of list 2
      SELECT val FROM list2
  ) y
  ON x.val = y.val
);
```

SQLFiddle demo --> http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5e47b/2

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you'll have to use AND conditions for every element of the 1-st set:

```
SELECT
    business.name
FROM
    business
WHERE
    4 NOT IN (1,2,3)
AND
    5 NOT IN (1,2,3)
```

Comment: But because the list is created by a nested query and not hard coded, I can't see a way it can be done with AND conditions because the list can be of variable size. Unless you can iterate over the first list to produce multiple ANDs. If this is possible could you provide an example. Thanks